# Enable / Disable Aero in C#/VB.NET or C++ Win32

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows, winapi

How to disable aero effects in C# .NET or C++ Win32 ???

This is my test code in C/C++, but only works if my app is runnig

```
#include <dwmapi.h>

int main()
{ 
    DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
    while(true); 
     //...
    return 0;
}
//LINK dwmapi.lib
```

Thanks

Edit: i figured it out

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hI, HINSTANCE hP, PSTR str, int c)
{ 
    DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
//Memory: 314KB
//CPU: 0%
```

Comment: Do you want to permanently disable them for the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern int DwmEnableComposition(bool fEnable);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DwmEnableComposition(false);

    // Your application here.
}
```